Can an ethical understanding based on evolved instincts be considered objective instead of relativistic?
Let's assume that humans have an in-built instinct to care for other humans, and that this helped us to survive in a harsh and dangerous environment, hence it was selected for. Small bands of homo sapiens among whom this instinct was relatively stronger, tended to survive and reproduce compared to others among whom it was weaker. Let's further assume that this instinct is the motivation for behaviour we would describe as moral, such as helping an old lady cross the street or diving into a river to rescue a drowning person.
If this were true, then it would mean that morality is ontologically prior to society and culture in that it has a genetic substrate, but like most human behaviours also requires a cultural context in which it is taught and fostered.
This would mean that in broad terms we could expect human moral behaviour to have a lot of commonality across societies in time and space, but differences in specifics, just as human languages have similar structures such as verbs and nouns, subjects and predicates, while having a great deal of culturally specific variety in the ways those linguistic structures are implemented.
It would also seem to mean that social norms can be evaluated somewhat objectively between cultures, if we consider how well they foster and incentivise this instinct. Generally, cultures can do various things with human tendencies: they can incentivise or discourage them, they can also seek to constrain them to specific contexts or channel them towards social goals, as happens with sex, or they can disparage and punish them, as self-preserving behaviour usually is if it happens at the expense of group survival in an existential crisis.
Society A might have a sense that all humans deserve to flourish, even in other societies, so it might highly value traits such as compassion and empathy.
Society B might believe that different cultures or societies exist in a state of competition, a kind of Social Darwinisnm. On that basis they might regard compassion with suspicion: good when it motivates you to rescue a comrade on the battlefield but a dangerous weakness when it makes you feel sorry for foreigners and try to help them.
It's natural to expect that Society A would cultivate the human moral instinct in an unqualified fashion, but Society B would seek to constrain and limit it while still turning it towards social goals.
If we consider that the moral instinct is part of what makes us human, then societies which expend more effort in fostering this instinct, and develop it more effectively in more sophisticated and wide-reaching ways, are objectively doing a better job of raising humans, all else being equal, and we could say this about Society A in comparison to Society B.
This could provide a somewhat objective yardstick for evaluating our own social progress and comparing social norms across different contexts.
Is this a position that could be made philosophically rigorous against cultural relativism?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'd see at least a couple of problems in trying to do this.  First, there would be conflicting evolutionary tensions.  In evolutionary theory, genetic traits are like "sailboats" being driven by various winds often blowing in opposite directions.  For example, some traits are said to evolve because it benefits the individual ("survival of the fittest"), which promotes selfishness; some, to benefit the kin, promoting family ties; others, to benefit the clan, which can cause immoral traits like racism, etc.; and others, to benefit the entire species, which might be more of what you're going for.  The problem is that with all these conflicting tensions, "morality" is looking more toward the direction of one of these "winds," not at the position of the "sailboat" itself, which is reacting to all of them.  It gets even more subjective if we try to synthesize a morality from several of these separate tensions (i.e., taking parts of individual, kin, clan, or species selection pressures).
The second problem I'd see is that the DNA is probably irrelevant to objectivity in this case, as discussed in some of the comments.  If we take all DNA as "moral," then we'd have to specify which behaviors are according to DNA and which aren't.  But if we select some DNA as "moral" and other as "immoral," how can we objectively tell which is which?  Most behaviors are affected by multiple genes, and the complexity of DNA itself is mindbending, as it can even be "multidimensional" in some respects, as I understand it.  In the end, if a person chooses "selflessness" as his standard of morality, I don't see how the objectivity of the standard changes, whether it's based in DNA or not.  If using DNA alone, every man could do what is right in his own eyes and use "evolved instinct" as his excuse; but I believe we need something more objective than that (Proverbs 21:2).  However, I do believe you're hitting on something profound in suggesting that there is a universal understanding of morality, innate in us globally, which helps us recognize what is right and what is wrong.  But I believe this is the law of God written on our hearts, rather than evolutionary DNA (Romans 2:15).

I like the analogy of the sailboat. On my desk I have this quote: Due to circumstances beyond my control I am the master of my fate and the captain of my soul. If we study psychology as early life biography and recurrent patterns of drama then we start to recognize patterns of ethical and moral variation via socialization. See, for example, The Ice Man and The Psychiatrist (2003). In early life the Ice Man was frequently beaten by his father with no hope for salvation. In adult life the Ice Man became a contract killer working for mobsters. His conscience was blocked (beaten out of him).

@PeterRankin I wouldn't make too much of DNA, except to the extent that transcribes part of the information that makes us human (not all, clearly, some info also comes from environmental factors).

Clearly there are conflicting evolutionary tensions, just as instincts can be contradictory: in a crisis you might experience the instinct to run away, and also the instinct to stay and help (seems like this sort of conflict is part of human experience). We could distinguish between instincts shared by all animals, and higher-order instincts shared by maybe mammals or primates, and instincts that only humans have or only have to a very high degree, if we want to explain why some instincts might be "better" or "more worth cultivating" or "more normative" than others.

@PeterRankin if there were a law of God written on our hearts, that would have to have a physical substrate given that our life including psychological experience all seems to take place through physical processes. My understanding of that statement would be simply, the way we are including our ideals and norms, doesn't just happen to be the way it is, it's also meant to be the way it is.
